# Using solr api in django without having to hit solr through a url

Tags: django, solr

Quick question, I was wondering if there is a way to use Solr's API without having to create a url and retrieve the response that way? I have google'd around, but to no avail. I don't want to use haystack, because I do not need all the bells and whistles that it has. I just want to be able to retrieve a response from Solr without having create a url, and render the response. By the way, I'm doing this in django/python.

Thanks for any leads you may give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [pysolr](http://code.google.com/p/pysolr/), and it's been great.